# What libraries and tools does LISP have that's usefull for games?

Tags: software-engineering

LISP is my favorite language and i don't wanna use c++ or any other language, but i don't know if there are much support for tools for game making, and i cant find much on the internet, anyone care to help?

Comment: Naughty Dog devs developed something pretty intense called GOAL when working on Jack and Daxter. Not a public product as far as I know though.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Oriented_Assembly_Lisp

Comment: Yeah but i can't use it I'm afraid because they didn't made it available to the public.

Comment: I guess if nothing else, this demonstrates the extent of what may be necessary to use LISP with game development today. If you are really devoted to it, plan to work for it it seems.

Comment: Side note: Naughty Dog dropped GOAL after the PS2, not least among their reasons was that it couldn't be shared with any other corporate studio and it was impossible to hire programmers.  In any case, GOAL was basically nothing more than a gameplay scripting language and not something their main engine was written in, even if they did go a bit overboard with it.

Comment: They dropped GOAL when they were bought by Sony. No telling what they would have done had they stayed independent. However, the designer of the language, Andy Gavin, retired soon after the acquisition, so I would guess they would have found an easier solution for PS3 development. From the notes he's posted on his website, it looks like maintaining GOAL was one of the hardest programming challenges in gaming history!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://3bb.cc/tutorials/cl-opengl/index.html

Here's a link to a few tutorials that show how to use OpenGL in LISP. Beyond that, so long as you are practicing, you should be able to structure some samples and eventually some games once you learn how to use OpenGL properly.

Also, though they are old, the old NeHe tutorials at http://nehe.gamedev.net have some LISP translation of at least their earliest tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Another idea is to use one of the .net lisp variants around, in which case you gain access to all that .net has to offer for gamedev.